# How to name a (no branch)-branch on git

Tags: git, git-branch

It happened somehow that I left the `master` branch and ended up on the `no branch` branch. How can I give this branch a meaningful name?

In detail: Calling `git branch` shows

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

and what I want (without changing any file) is to have e.g.

```
* extraBranchIEndedUpWith
  master
```

`git status` is clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"no branch" is not a branch, as the name says. It means you have checked out a revision that isn't the tip of a branch.

To create a branch of it, simply

```
git checkout -b extraBranchIEndedUpWith
```

Just like you would create any other branch from your current revision.